# Repeat notification in every month

Tags: swift3, nsdatecomponents, localnotification, usernotifications

Following line of code could repeat a local notification in every week, right?:

```
let triggerWeekly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)
```

But how to repeat a local notification in every month? What the date components will be needed to schedule a monthly notification?

Comment: Did you try the common components or the dates? Like .day?

Comment: @Willeke No! I didn't tried yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this :

```
let triggerMonthly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerMonthly, repeats: true)
```

Comment: What if the date that'
s being schedule on the is 31st it would repeat every two months

Comment: And in February it would even be worst. It would never schedule also the 30th and the 29th maybe yes maybe not

Comment: @LeoDabus That means it's impossible to create?

Comment: Based on experimenting in a playground it seems like it rounds up to the first day of the following month in that case rather than skipping those days.